# 'Sich verwandeln zu' vs. 'sich verwandeln in'

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification

Könnte mir jemand den Unterschied zwischen *sich verwandeln in* und *sich verwandeln zu* erklären?

Ich habe im Duden nachgeschlagen und zwei Beispiele gefunden:

> Das kleine Mädchen hat sich inzwischen **in** eine junge Dame verwandelt.

aber

> Während der Regenzeit verwandeln sich die Bäche **zu** reißenden Strömen.

Ich lese gerade "Die Verwandlung", und hier findet Gregor Samsa sich

> „**Zu** einem ungeheueren Ungeziefer verwandelt“.

Bei Langenscheidt finde ich nur weitere Beispiele mit dem Gebrauch von **in**:

> Zeus verwandelte sich **in** einen Schwan.
>
> Seine Liebe hat sich **in** Hass verwandelt.

Etwas hänselt mich hier :D

Comment: Das scheint mir im Wesentlichen eine Stilfrage zu sein. *Zu* ist heutzutage für diesen Zweck eher unüblich.

Comment: Hmm, ich würde "zu" selten und nur bei quantitativen / weniger radikalen  Veränderungen nutzen. Dem aber widerspricht der Satz Kafkas!

Comment: Anders gesagt, ich fände folgendes optimal: "die Raupe verwandelt sich zum Schmetterling" / "die Hexe verwandelt sich in einen Schmetterling". Kafkas Wortwahl passt nicht zu meiner. Das zweite Beispiel dagegen vollkommen. Das "zu" mit seinem Bezug zur Richtung passt für mich am besten zur graduellen Änderung. Ich bemerke bei mir auch die Tendenz mit "zu" eher "wandeln" zu sagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Zu* betont mehr die relativ langsame Veränderung, d.h. jemand/etwas wird (langsam) zu etwas, eine Verlaufsdarstellung sozusagen. *In* stellt hier mehr den Ausganspunkt dem Ergebnis gegenüber als zwei Zustände, die verglichen werden. Wird doch *zu* verwendet, obwohl der Übergang plötzlich stattfindet, klingt es eher veraltet.

Allerdings lässt sich die Grenze nicht eindeutig ziehen. Es würde sich nicht als unpassend für mich anhören, wenn man statt *zu* *in* verwendet. Umgedreht geht's oft nicht. *Zu* wird hier vielleicht einmal von *in* vollständig ersetzt werden.

Comment: Genauso hätte ich es auch erklärt.